# Function not properly splitting data up from object in console log, but displays right as anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, javascript-objects

It seems my function isn't properly displaying the names in the console log split up once clicked, as I'm trying to implement properly. It's giving me this undefined error displayed here:
[image]

However the code that it's erroring out, "response.data[i]" , is properly displaying on the html side in the anchor tag as seen in the code (from below's link) and this screenshot:

[image]

So how is it undefined when clicked to split up the name in console log, but clearly working as it's being displayed? Also the console.log(response.data); command is clearly displaying the response.data 's as shown here:

[image]

So I'm just not getting how to fix this to properly display the names in console log once clicked , wether it be a 2 word name or 3 word name.

Code:

```
function getGroupWall() {
    $("#groupUL").html("");
    FB.api('/421727124532461/feed', 'get', function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
        for (i=10, j=response.data.length; i<=j; i++) {
            function splitName(txt){
                var myString = txt;

                var mySplitResult = myString.split(" ");

                console.log("The first element is " + mySplitResult[0]); 
                console.log("<br /> The second element is  " + mySplitResult[1]); 
                console.log("<br /> The third element is  " + mySplitResult[2]); 

            };
            $("#groupUL").append("<li>" + "<h4>Item Description:</h4> " + response.data[i].message + "<br /> " + "<h2>Posted By:</h2> <a href='#' id='splitNames'>" + response.data[i].from.name + "</a>" + "<br />"+ "<h4># of Replys: </h4>" + response.data[i].comments.count + "<br />" +  "<a href='" + response.data[i].link + "' target='new' style='text-align:right;'>(external url)</a>" + "<br /> " + "<img src='"+response.data[i].picture+"'>" + "</li><br />");
            $("#splitNames").click(function(){ splitName(response.data[i].from.name) });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical closure problem.

The value of `i` will be `response.data.length` when the `click` handler fires.

You have to **bind** the value for `i` like so:

```
$("#splitNames").click((function (i) { // extra "(" indicating immediate invocation
    // return an anonymous function that has a value for "i" in it's scope
    return function (event) { // event is the click event, or whatever is usually passed to it
        splitName(response.data[i].from.name)
    }
}(i))); // immediate invocation to bind "i"
```

You could also do this:

```
$("#splitNames").click((function (item) {
    return function (event) {
        splitName(item.from.name)
    }
}(response.data[i])));
```

I hope this helps you understand how closures work.

Comment: Great that seems to work out great, only problems now are that when I click a name, it displays every single objects data from name rather then just the one clicked. Also it seems the first link(li anchor) on the page is the only one that console logs while the rest don't fire anything.

Comment: Also getting this in console TypeError: response.data[i] is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

...</a>" + "<br />"+ "<h4># of Replys: </h4>" + response.data[i].comments.count + "...

Comment: There are other problems with your code. You aren't allowed to define functions or variables in a for-loop. Some of your logic may depend on that. A for-loop in JavaScript doesn't actually create a new scope. Only functions make new scopes.

Comment: I changed it from #splitName to .splitName (id to class) and now all links are clickable, I believe that had to do with ids counter acting with one another and only letting the first one to be clicked. They're still displaying them all and not them single handedly when clicked still. Heres my new code:http://pastebin.com/nYZEpU7k